# Jquery check a checkbox in a table

Tags: jquery, html

In my project i've got this table:

```
<table id="filter-table" class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Accessory</td>
      <td>Typology</td>
      <td>Check</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Acc 1</td>
      <td id="typology">
        <div class="idtypology" style="display:none">1</div>Typology name</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and this dropdown menu:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">Type 1</option>
  <option value="2">Type 2</option>
  <option value="3">Type 3</option>
  <option value="5">Select All</option>
</select>
```

The value of the dropdownmenù option is the same of the hidden div with the class idtypology. On the change of this element (with the .change() jquery function) I want to be able to check all the checkbox in the `<tr>` that have the idtypology div value = to the option value actually selected

for example if the drop down value is 1 I want to check all the checkboxes with the idtypology = 1

is this possible?

Comment: show us your attempts

Comment: http://news.3yen.com/wp-content/images/Is-it-possible.gif

Comment: i don't know how i can do. this one of my very first exercise in jquery. the only thing i know is to select the filter dropdown menu but i don't know how to change the elements inside my table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use HTML5 data attribute:

```
<table id="filter-table" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>  Accessory </td>
            <td> Typology </td>
            <td> Check </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-typology="1">
            <td> Acc 1</td> 
            <td id="typology">Typology name</td>
            <td> <input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And JS

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
    var typology = $(this).val();
    $('#filter-table').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", false);
    $('#filter-table tr[data-typology="'+typology +'"]').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", true);
});
```

Comment: I use table ID as selector because the same data attribute could be used somewhere else

Answer (score 2):

Set up your html with something like this....

```
 <td id="typology">Typology name</td>
 <td><input type="checkbox" data-idtypology='1' /></td>
```

then use jquery with something like this

```
 $(document).on('change', 'select', function(){
     var val= $(this).val();
     $('[data-idtypology="'+val+'"]').prop('checked', true);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Below is an approach to check checkboxes, you can change according to your requirements. I hope it helps.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<table id="filter-table" class="table table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>  Accessory </td>
        <td> Typology </td>
        <td> Check </td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td> Acc 1</td> 
        <td id="typology"> <div class="idtypology" style="display:none"> 1</div> Typology name</td>
        <td> <input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Acc 2</td> 
        <td id="typology"> <div class="idtypology" style="display:none"> 2</div> Typology name</td>
        <td> <input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <tr>
</tbody><br />
<select>
  <option value="0">Select All</option>
  <option value="1">Type 1</option>
  <option value="2">Type 2</option>
  <option value="3">Type 3</option>
</select>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("select").change(function(){
        var v=$(this).val();
        $(".idtypology:contains('"+v+"')").parents("tr").children().find("input[type='checkbox']").attr("checked", true);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First change your html like this

```
$(function () {
$('#filter').change(function () {
    var filterid = $(this).val();
    $(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    $('.type'+filterid).prop('checked', true);
});//click
```

});

```
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td> Acc 1</td> 
        <td id="typology"> <div class="idtypology" style="display:none"> 1</div> Typology name</td>
        <td> <input type="checkbox" class="type1" /></td>
    <tr>
       <tr>
        <td> Acc 1</td> 
        <td id="typology"> <div class="idtypology" style="display:none"> 3</div> Typology name</td>
        <td> <input type="checkbox"  class="type3"/></td>
    <tr>
            <tr>
        <td> Acc 1</td> 
        <td id="typology"> <div class="idtypology" style="display:none"> 2</div> Typology name</td>
        <td> <input type="checkbox" class="type2" /></td>
    <tr>
            <tr>
        <td> Acc 1</td> 
        <td id="typology"> <div class="idtypology" style="display:none"> 2</div> Typology name</td>
        <td> <input type="checkbox"  class="type2"/></td>
    <tr>
                 <tr>
        <td> Acc 1</td> 
        <td id="typology"> <div class="idtypology" style="display:none"> 1</div> Typology name</td>
        <td> <input type="checkbox"  class="type1"/></td>
    <tr>

</tbody>


<select id="filter">
    <option value="" disabled selected>--Select--</option>
  <option value="1">Type 1</option>
  <option value="2">Type 2</option>
  <option value="3">Type 3</option>
  <option value="5">Select All</option>
</select>
```